# How to get access token from redirect Uri in java?

Tags: gmail-api

i am try to use gmail api for learning purpose. I created gmail sign in. After Allow i am redirect a new web pages. which address is http://localhost:8080/Zon/Confirm?code=4/v4-CqVXkhiTkn9uapv6V0iqUmelHNnbLRr1EbErzkQw#

so how to get access token from this address?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use localhost for redirection. Think, how would Google Servers know your address to send you the Authentication Token?

Redirect Uri must be publicly accessible so that Google OAuth services can redirect the users after authentication to your redirect URL. You can not complete OAuth cycle using localhost.

Try the API with a publicly hosted site.